# Objeto está vindo nulo

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código, porém o o `var ob` esta vindo nulo.

```
<head>
<script>
   function pisca(item) {
       var ob = document.getElementById(item);

       if (ob.style.color=="red"){
          ob.style.color="black";
       }else{
          ob.style.color="red";
       }
   } 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="piscar" style="color:#F00">
   Texto piscando
</div>

 <script>
    t = setInterval("pisca('piscar')",500);
 </script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Bom dia. Vc verificou isso no console, que está vindo nulo?

Comment: "var ob esta vindo nulo." Não seria antes `undefined` ? Em que situações isso está a acontecer ? Tem como mostrar isso para nós ? Onde está a ver esse nulo ?

Comment: Vale lembrar que o `var ob` só tem valor dentro da função `pisca`. Se quiser que ele tenha escopo global, teria que fazer fora da função `var ob;` e dentro da função sem o `var`, apenas `ob = document.getElementById(item);`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, deu certo era apenas isso mesmo!!

Answer (score 0):

tentei simular o seu problema aqui, mas o mesmo não ocorreu.:

```js
function pisca(item) {
  var ob = document.getElementById(item);
  if (ob.style.color == "red") {
    ob.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    ob.style.color = "red";
  }
}

t = setInterval("pisca('piscar')", 500);
```

```html
<div id="piscar" style="color:#F00">
  Texto piscando
</div>
```

apesar que eu alteraria a forma de chamar a função pisca no `setInterval`, afinal esta forma não é recomendada ([LEIA MAIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval))

```js
function pisca(item) {
  var ob = document.getElementById(item);
  if (ob.style.color == "red") {
    ob.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    ob.style.color = "red";
  }
}

t = setInterval(function () {
  pisca('piscar')
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="piscar" style="color:#F00">
  Texto piscando
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, esqueci de falar que estou incluindo esse codigo no jsp, e nesse jsp estou usando o <h:form que está fazendo por algum motivo que esse script fique com objeto nulo.                                             Não sei se consegui explicar, mas quando tiro o <h: form ele funciona e tenho varios scripts e eles estão funcionando normalmente só esse que está dando problema.

Comment: então o seu problema não é com o `JavaScript`, mas com o `jsp` (o qual foge completamente ao meu domínio), aconselho que analise o HTML final (direto no browser) e veja se está como esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Como a variável `ob` foi declarada com `var` dentro da função `pisca()`, ela só tem escopo dentro da função.

Você pode resolver fazendo com que ela tenha escopo global removendo o `var`:

```
function pisca(item) {
    ob = document.getElementById(item);

    if (ob.style.color=="red"){
       ob.style.color="black";
    }else{
       ob.style.color="red";
    }
}
```

> Após a execução da função, a variável `ob` passa a ter um valor
>   global.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function pisca(item) {
    ob = document.getElementById(item);

    if (ob.style.color=="red"){
       ob.style.color="black";
    }else{
       ob.style.color="red";
    }
}

function teste(){
   console.log(ob);
}

pisca('piscar');
```

```html
<div id="piscar" style="color:#F00">
   Texto piscando
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="teste()" value="Verificar valor de ob">
```

Comment: Muito Obrigadoo vou testar =).

Comment: E aí amigo, deu certo?

Comment: Opa deu sim mtu obrigado =)